# Attempt to call global 'gameover' (a table value)

Tags: lua, coronasdk

So i'm working on a little game using onCollision event's :

```
local function onCollision(event)
    if event.phase == "began" and gameIsActive == true then
        local obj1 = event.object1; 
        local obj2 = event.object2; 

        if obj1.name == "bill" then
        if     obj2.name == "rocks" then gameover()
        elseif obj2.name == ""   then 
        end
    end
    end
end
Runtime:addEventListener( "collision", onCollision )
```

But i have a bit of a problem the code works as expected the first time it runs but is you restart the game i'm getting this error :

```
File: game.lua 
Line: 649 
Attempt to call global 'gameover' (a table value) 

stack traceback: game.lua:649: in function <game.lua:643> ?: in function <?:221>

649 = if obj2.name == "rocks" then gameover()  
643 = local function onCollision(event)
```

Any idea what this could be?

gameover function :

```
function gameover()

rightTAP:removeEventListener("tap", movePLAYERr) 
leftTAP:removeEventListener("tap", movePLAYERl) 

timer.pause(spawnBits)
timer.pause(Rockspawner1)
timer.pause(tmrscore)
timer.pause(updateScoretimer)
timer.pause(spawnDinosControll)

audio.pause( drillingChannel )

drillbg.isVisible = false
scoreText.isVisible = false

Restartg = display.newText( "Restart", 0, 0,nil, 20)
Restartg:setFillColor(0, 0, 0)
screenGroup:insert(Restartg)
Restartg.x= display.contentWidth/2
Restartg.y= display.contentHeight/2 + 160

Restartg:addEventListener("tap", RestartGame1)

end
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

fixed by adding "transition.pause( thisRock )" to the gameover function

Answer (score 3):

The error message is clear: you are trying to call `gameover` and it has a table value instead of a function value. You get the same error is you run the following: `gameover = {}; gameover()`.

This means that either you are not correctly defining `gameover` function or overwriting `gameover` value somewhere in your script.

Comment: added the gameover function  to the question

Answer (score 0):

if you have an object of functions you can call whit the key that you use to declare.

example

```
el = {}

print(el)
table: 0x7f8fe9e003f0

el.f1 = function()
print('hola')
end


el.f1()
hola
```

Answer (score 0):

On restart you have to remove all Runtime listeners. Otherwise they will be still listening and it may cause errors, because they lead to already removed methods.

Place it in RestartGame1:

```
Runtime:removeEventListener( "collision", onCollision )
```